# Command `bundle` unrecognized.Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Run the react-native bundle command in terminal from the root
>   directory of your app

What is the root directory of my app? I am trying to run UIExplorer (on my device) from the official repo but its always giving me this message when I run

```
react-native bundle
```

**Command `bundle` unrecognized.Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?**

I think I tried pretty much every directory inside `/react-native-master`

Comment: Which version of react native are you running? The root directory would be the one with your index.ios.js.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Running react-native@0.4.0 and react-native-cli@0.1.3.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run `react-native bundle`.

You should follow the 'OPTION 2' instruction in AppDelegate.m, you will find something like the screenshots below:
[image]

The instruction in the React-native website is not so clear, a clearer instructions will be:

- Open iOS/AppDelegate.m
- Comment out jsCodeLocation = [NSURL
  URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
- Uncomment jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
  URLForResource:@"main"    withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
- Run the curl given in 'OPTION 2' (e.g.
  `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle`)
- if this fails add the --ipv4 flag to the end of it.
- In XCode, right click on your project directory and click    Add
  Files to "Project Name Here" - choose the main.jsbundle file that
  you generated.

Referenced from: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240

If you still can't run it, check your main.jsbundle if it contains error. If it does, make sure the given curl path is correct. I end up changing the curl to `curl http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerApp.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd go project dir and run git bash show Command `bundle` unrecognized. bat cmd does not show an error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).